# Convert list data into dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have extracted the content of a script from a website. Now I want to transform the received data list to a dictionary to have an easier search.

The **json data** (json_data) looks like that (part of):

```
 'id': 'dungeons-and-raids',
    'name': 'Dungeons & Raids',
    'regionId': 'US',
    'groups': [{
        'content': {
            'lines': [{
                'icon': 'ability_toughness',
                'name': 'Fortified',
                'url': '/affix=10/fortified'
            }, {
                'icon': 'spell_nature_cyclone',
                'name': 'Storming',
                'url': '/affix=124/storming'
            }, {
                'icon': 'ability_ironmaidens_whirlofblood',
                'name': 'Bursting',
                'url': '/affix=11/bursting'
            }],
            'icons': 'large'
        },
        'id': 'mythicaffix',
        'name': 'Mythic+ Affixes',
    },
   ...
```

And this is my complete Python 3.11 **script**:

```
import re
import json
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request(
    "https://www.wowhead.com/today-in-wow", headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
)
html_page = urlopen(req).read().decode("utf-8")

json_data = re.search(
    r"TodayInWow\(WH\.ge\('tiw-standalone'\), (.*), true\);", html_page
)
json_data = json.loads(json_data.group(1))

data = {
    (d["id"], d["regionId"]): {dd["id"]: dd for dd in d["groups"]} for d in json_data
}

for affixline, affixp in enumerate(data[("dungeons-and-raids", 
"US")]["mythicaffix"]['content']['lines']):

    affixurl = affixp['url']
    affixname = affixp['name']
    affixid = affixline
```

This gives me the **error**:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

It seems `dd["id"]` returns "None", but I don't know why. What is the correct way to use the dictionary in this case?

Comment: Which line is responsible for the error message ?

Comment: @rr_goyal Line 15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a check if the returned group from the server is not `null`:

```py
import re
import json
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request(
    "https://www.wowhead.com/today-in-wow", headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
)
html_page = urlopen(req).read().decode("utf-8")

json_data = re.search(
    r"TodayInWow\(WH\.ge\('tiw-standalone'\), (.*), true\);", html_page
)
json_data = json.loads(json_data.group(1))

data = {
    (d["id"], d["regionId"]): {dd["id"]: dd for dd in d["groups"] if dd} for d in json_data  # <-- add check if group is not null
}

for affixline, affixp in enumerate(data[("dungeons-and-raids", "US")]["mythicaffix"]['content']['lines']):
    affixurl = affixp['url']
    affixname = affixp['name']
    print(affixurl, affixname)
```

Prints:

```
/affix=10/fortified Fortified
/affix=124/storming Storming
/affix=11/bursting Bursting
```